# Heroku rake db:migrate doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

im having this issue when i try to deploy my ruby on rails application to heroku, i check different posts here, because i saw this issue before but i couldnt fix it.
when i try to run:

```
$ heroku rake db:migrate
```

I get a lot of these ones: `DEPRECATION WARNING`:

and then:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to change my Gemfile with 'pg' and my group :assets do to :production, i know im missing something but i could'nt figured out what.

Some ideas?

Also when I go to the app url, I get this:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Thanks in advance for any suggest and help!!!

Comment: What versions of Rails / Ruby are you running.  I assume you're running on the Bamboo Ruby 1.9.2 stack

Comment: im running ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails Rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Postgres on Heroku, you can't use sqlite3 because Heroku prohibits you from saving to the file system. So add the pg gem to your production bundle and re-deploy then your migrations should run.

Comment: how do i change my config to use postgreql (that the problem i think) but i dont know how to change it i tryed running: gem install postgres-pr but and adding: group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
and running: bundle install --without production, too... im quite confused...

Answer (score 0):

Answer here is simple, add the following `production` in your gemfile as:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Your local machine won't work with this production, so we now have to bundle it by ignoring PostgreSQL gem which can be done as:

```
bundle install --without production
```

After this, try `heroku rake db:migrate`. Must work.

Good luck

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that im gonna try but im litle confused about something: when i write group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end should i delete the rest of gems? i also run gem install postgres-pr and shold i change databas.yml to:  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
 is that ok?

Comment: @FernandoLöpez in Your Gemfile

Comment: Err. Didn't quite get you. You have to open `Gemfile` file present in your app directory structure. You can add that like every other gems are listed in that file.

Comment: sorry i didnt explain my self so well... iv already change my Gemfile (i just added :production do
  gem 'pg') and i installed bundle (did well) but shoul i change my databas.yml and insted sqlite3 write postgresql? isn it? (when i try to make an scaffold i have an error (but i know that is because im not doing something well in the db configuration)

Comment: I JUST DID WHAT YOU SAYD AND IT WORKS PERFECT!!! i dont know what i did wrong before but it works now!! thank you very very much to all!!